# Adjacency Matrix of Graph

Tags: data-structures, graph, dynamic-arrays, adjacency-matrix

I am writing a code for implementing Adjacency Matrix for graph.But I am getting runtime error.Can anyone suggest where I am wrong?

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <malloc.h>

struct Graph{
    int V;
    int E;
    int **Adj;
};

void test(struct Graph *graph)
{
    graph->E = 5;
    graph->V = 4;
    graph->Adj = malloc(sizeof(graph->V * graph->V));
    graph->Adj[0][0] = 9;
    graph->Adj[0][1] = 7;
    graph->Adj[0][2] = 2;
    graph->Adj[0][3] = 5;
    printf("Hello %d\n",graph->Adj[0][2]);    
}
int main()
{
    struct Graph *graph = malloc(sizeof(struct Graph));
    test(graph); 
}
```

If I do the same in main function it works.I don't understand what am I doing wrong when I write test function and do it?

Code when done in main function:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <malloc.h>

struct Graph{
    int V;
    int E;
    int **Adj;
};


int main()
{
    struct Graph *graph = malloc(sizeof(struct Graph));
    graph->E = 5;
    graph->V = 4;
    graph->Adj = malloc(sizeof(graph->V * graph->V));
    graph->Adj[0][0] = 9;
    graph->Adj[0][1] = 7;
    graph->Adj[0][2] = 2;
    graph->Adj[0][3] = 5;
    printf("Hello %d\n",graph->Adj[0][2]);

}
```

Getting Runtime error.While debugging for `test function` it works till `graph->Adj = malloc(sizeof(graph->V * graph->V));` but at `graph->Adj[0][0] = 9;` it gives error.Why???

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Updated the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing a wrong malloc. You are using pointer to pointer. So, you will have to malloc first to get the array pointer allocated dynamically. Then you will have to allocate it for every row.

Try this:

```
 graph->Adj = (int **)malloc(graph->v * sizeof(int *));
    for (i=0; i<graph->v; i++)
         graph->Adj[i] = (int *)malloc(graph->v * sizeof(int));
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply.I know that method but I want to know why my method is wrong?

Comment: Updated the answer

Comment: But when I do the same in main function it works.Why there and not in test function?